# shell script running but not the command inside the script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a peculiar problem. Below is the shell script I am using via command-line script is working fine. But the same script when I execute via commvault post backup script is running but not executing the command inside that script. Any idea why it is not executing the command via remote execution.

`more sat-stop.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$HOME=/root

NOW=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")

#Redhat 6.4

foreman-maintain service  stop | tee -a /usr/local/scripts/sat-stop-$NOW.log 2>&1

sleep 30

exit 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: what does `type foreman-maintain` return?

Comment: `export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$HOME=/root` Something is off here. I am not sure what your intention around `HOME` here is. My best guess is, you wanted `export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$HOME`

Comment: ...or wanted `HOME=/root` to be a separate assignment...

Comment: @Sivakumar ...so, "not executing" doesn't really tell us much. Does it give you an error message that shows you how/why something isn't executing? If so, what is that exact message? If not, how do you know that it's not being run, vs being run and not working as you intend?

Comment: If you add `set -x` to the beginning of the script, and possibly also `exec 2>$(mktemp -t sat-stop.log.XXXXXX)` to make it write to a logfile you can read later, what's in those logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charles Duffy and @anishane

Yes you are correct.

I alter the script as below and it is working now. foreman-maintain stop katello-services in Red Hat satellite.

more /usr/local/scripts/sat-stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export HOME=/root

#Satellite service stop script with function adddate for time stamp
#Create 16-08-2018 Siva AEST
NOW=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")

#katello-service stop | tee -a /usr/local/scripts/sat-stop-$NOW.log 2>&1
#Satellite 6.4 
foreman-maintain service  stop | tee -a /usr/local/scripts/sat-stop-$NOW.log 2>&1

sleep 30
exit 0
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for the delay response.